# Compare two columns in different tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

Table `vehicles`

```
regno     make      status

KBT567K   ISUZU     operating
KAD897L   DOGDE     operating
KAT876K   JAGUAR    grounded
KAW564H   FERRARI   operating
```

Table `contributions`

```
regno      amount    timestamp

KBT567K     200      2015-03-24 18:10:13 
KAD897L     100      2015-03-24 12:32:16
KBT567K     150      2015-03-25 11:06:32
```

I am trying to pull a query where I only get a list of `regno` from table vehicles that have not contributed on `2015-03-25` while their `status` is `'operating'`

I have tried this query below but doesn't work. Any help will be highly appreciated

```
select 
  regno
from
  vehicles
where
  regno not in (
    select
      contributions.regno
    from
      contributions,vehicles
    WHERE
      DATE_FORMAT(contributions.timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d') > '2015-03-25' AND 
      DATE_FORMAT(contributions.timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d') > '2015-03-24'
  ) AND
  vehicles.status = 'operating' ORDER BY vehicles.regno asc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out the solution for this

```
 Select DISTINCT regno from vehicles where status = 'operating' AND vehicles.regno not in (select regno from contributions WHERE DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d') > '2015-03-24') and DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d') != '2015-03-25' ORDER BY regno asc
```

Thanks all for your time. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can try this SQL:

```
select DISTINCT regno 
from vehicles
where status = 'operating' AND regno in (select regno from contributions WHERE DATE_FORMAT(timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d') != '2015-03-25') 
ORDER BY regno asc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JOIN`

```
select vehicles.regno
from vehicles
LEFT JOIN contributions ON vehicles.regno = contributions.regno
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(contributions.timestamp,'%Y-%m-%d') != '2015-03-25'
AND WHERE vehicles.status = "operating"
ORDER BY vehicles.regno asc
```

Comment: And `WHERE vehicles.status = "operating"`.

Comment: Ohh yaah. Miss that bit. Thankyou :D

Comment: thanks but the query does not not work propery . its giving lots of redudunt row

Comment: i only want to pick the vehicles that have not contributed on 2015-03-25 i think i should have a result of 2 KBT567K, KAW564H .

Comment: Select Distinct vehicles.regno to avoid duplicates or Add Group by vehicles.regno and Use Left join instead of Join

Comment: @mbaula In that case, use `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Also I think `AND WHERE` is not valid SQL :-)

Comment: the query above still gives rows that have vehicles grounded

Comment: hello guys i found the solution you can see it below